# Converting String to int array

Tags: python, arrays, django, python-3.x, numpy

I'm stucked with some problem. 
I've sent int array from JS to Python via AJAX and it has been converted to JSON (as I used JSON.stringify()), so now it's a string "[1,2,3,4,5]". 
How can I convert it in Python back to int array [1,2,3,4,5]?
I've tried to convert this array to numpy array `np.asarray(features_user, dtype="int")`, but this not helped

Comment: You can call `json.loads` on that string to convert it into a python list.

Comment: @chrisz thank you so much! You saved my time, as I`m making diploma project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.loads()` is what you're looking for. make sure you add the `s` in load. the `s` stands for `string`.

So `json.load` is for a file, `json.loads` for a string

```
>>> import json
>>> a = "[1,2,3,4,5]"
>>> b = json.loads(a)
>>> b,type(b)
([1, 2, 3, 4, 5] , <class 'list'>)
```